# how to get an items from class of items

Tags: ios, swift

I have a cell in (Table View List) of animals and i want to get from class of informations about the animals, what I want to do is get the name of the animal and put it in the cell.

This is ViewController class

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var TableViewList: UITableView!

    var NotKiller = Array<Animal>()
    var Killer = Array<Animal>()
    var Sections = ["NotKiller", "Killer"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadAnimals()
    }

    @IBAction func buAllAnimals(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return NotKiller.count

        } else {
            return Killer.count
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return Sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return Sections[section]
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        if indexPath.section==0 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "" //here where I want to add the name

        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "" // here where I want to add the name
        }

        return cell
    } 
    func loadAnimals(){
    //here where I add the Items in to arrays
    }
}
```

This is the Animal class

```
import Foundation

class Animal {
    var Killing:String?
    var Name:String?
    var Des:String?
    var Image:String?

    init(Killing:String, Name:String, Des:String, Image:String) {
        self.Killing = Killing
        self.Name = Name
        self.Des = Des
        self.Image = Image
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do it

```
if indexPath.section==0 {
    cell.textLabel?.text = NotKiller[indexPath.row].Name
} else {
    cell.textLabel?.text = Killer[indexPath.row].Name
}
```

---

As a side note, your variable names should start with a lowercase letter to easily tell them apart from type name. `Killer` looks like it's a type but it's really a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    if indexPath.section==0 {
        cell.textLabel?.text = NotKiller[indexPath.row].name

    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = Killer[indexPath.row].name
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: thak you so much <3